# Как сделать высоту блока <div> в зависимости от контента внутри?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Здраствуйте. Создаю сайт(блог) двух колоночной структуры. Основную часть должна занимать лента новый записей. Но тут я столкнулся с проблемой, что при указании в CSS свойстве блока ленты `height: auto;` блок не подстраивается под другие "дивы" внутри, а просто растягивается на всю страницу. Указание процентов даёт адаптивный размер к размеру экрана, но в данной ситуации это не важно. Все блоки в таком враппере:

```
.wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  width: 98%;
  height: 300%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  top:0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

Лента:

```
.main_content{
  position: absolute;
  width: 78%;
  top: 4%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 91.5%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 74px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset 0px 0px 8px -109px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Ещё одна проблема заключается в том, что если в врапперском
`height: 98%;`
указать 100%, то на экране появляется нежелательная полоса горизонтальной прокрутки. Подскажите пожалуйста как тут быть?

Comment: Нужно больше информации, html кол, и думаю лучше ще скины как сейчас и как +- должно быть.

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Где `div` - название нужного блока

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй `overflow: auto;`
Этот параметр создаст окно внутри окна, тем самым по своему уменьшим общий размер